# asp.net core 2.0 autenticação com cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

estou fazendo uma autenticação usando cookies seguindo os exemplos

[Custom Authentication in ASP.Net-Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095076/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core)

[Creating a simple login in ASP.NET Core 2 using Authentication and Authorization (NOT Identity)](http://future-shock.net/blog/post/creating-a-simple-login-in-asp.net-core-2-using-authentication-and-authorization-not-identity)

Consegui fazer, já verificando os dados no banco, más me surgiu uma dúvida, e não encontrei a resposta, como faço para obter os dados do usuário logado após a autenticação?

vi que na parte do código abaixo ele armazena alguns dados do usuário, então como faço para pegar esses dados por exemplo o código do usuário para mostrar somente os registros relacionados a ele?

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginData.Username));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginData.Username));
```

Por exemplo na página de edição dos dados do usuário, precisaria pegar os valores setados em **ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier** e **ClaimTypes.Name**, como faria isso? ou preciso armazenar esses dados em sessão?

Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Olá, 
uma rápida pesquisa sobre Claims você encontrará muita coisa.

como você seguiu o tutorial: Creating a simple login in ASP.NET Core 2 using Authentication and Authorization (NOT Identity),

experimente colocar esse código na página Index:

```
<p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
<ul>
    @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
    {
        <li>@claim.Type : @claim.Value</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dessa forma:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

Caso queira saber se o usuário está autenticado:

```
@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Caso queira saber se o usuário pertence a um tipo de perfil (Role):

```
@User.IsInRole("Administrador")
```